# И снова о блатных

Tags: омонимы

Вопрос о "сборе блатных и нищих" натолкнул меня на другой вопрос: а как так получилось, что слово "блатной" стало означать и личные связи ("достать по блату"), и все, что связано с криминальным миром: "блатные песни", "блатной жаргон"?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, расскажу вам один анекдот: «Заходит в тюремную камеру деревенский парень  с большими кулями в руках, арестованный за то, что трактор утопил  спьяну, и спрашивает: 
- Воры есть у камеры?
- Есть! – отвечают ему.
- А сматращы?
- Есть, - говорит тот, кто является смотрящим – самым авторитетным человеком в камере.
- Так гляди, - обращается к нему тракторист, - каб воры маё сала не пакрали!»
Дело в том, что среди элиты воровского мира слово «блатной» - неприемлемо. Там несколько иные определения: «бродяга», «порядочный арестант», «вор» и т.д. Если вы назовёте «блатным» кого-то из них в лицо, то будете выглядеть, как тракторист из данного анекдота и не дай вам бог узнать, что с ним произошло далее. Блатной – это тот, кто имеет блат, не более того. Но почему  этим словом, всё же, нередко называют и преступников, имеющих «вес» в криминальном мире? В советское время обычному человеку в ресторан можно было попасть, лишь отстояв огромную очередь,  у кого был блат – в очереди стоять не надо было. Кто были завсегдатаи ресторанов? Бандиты и спекулянты. Именно к последним понятие «блатной» и относилось, но, поскольку мы – обыватели, любим всех чесать под одну гребёнку, блатными в наших глазах становятся все те, чьи возможности несколько расширены, для кого материальные блага (обратите внимание на это слово) - доступнее. Что же такое «блат»? – Замкнутый круг избранных, помогающих друг другу обретать материальные блага. Наводит на аналогию с циферблатом – замкнутым кругом избранных цифр. Структура же криминального мира более походит на государственную. Хотя,  энциклопедии и интернет предполагают немецкое,   еврейское, польское происхождение этого слова, уверен, происходит оно из понятия замкнутого круга. В заключении скажу: слова могут прийти в язык случайно, но не случайно на языке оседают.

Comment: Мнение  интересное.  А  другие  мнения на  эту  тему  есть ?  В  досоветское  время  это  слово  бытовало ?

Comment: Подозреваю, что это слово не бытовало и в довоенное время.

Answer (score 1):

Если брать за источник немецкий, то блат - значит "лист". Лист - это список, какое-то определённое число людей. отсюда и блатной - занесённый в список.

Answer (score 1):

ИЗ СЛОВАРЕЙ

ШАНСКИЙ.Блат - знакомство, используемое в корыстных целях. Исконное. Из воровского арго, от blat (польск.) - укрывающий по знакомству, восходит к blat (европ. идиш) - близкий (человек).

ФАСМЕР: Блат - (воровск. арго), отсюда блатная музыка "воровской жаргон, арго". Ср. польск. blat "укрыватель" из еврейско-нем. blat "посвященный, согласный.

Блатной - Die Blatte (нем. идиш) - лист, бумажка, записочка. Тот кто устраивался по блату, имел "бумажку" от нужного человека.

МНЕНИЕ ИЗ ИНТЕРНЕТА http://otvet.mail.ru/question/24786318

БЛАТНОЙ – ЭТО ЕДИНОКРОВНЫЙ

Блат означает кровь. Слово ведет свое происхождение из идиша, еврейского жаргона немецкого языка, сравнить blood,(англ.) – кровь. С советских времен сохраняются у нас выражения доставать по блату или у него там блат. По блату достать – когда твои единокровные, евреи то есть, тебе помогают добыть желаемое.

Раньше клятва воровская скреплялась кровью. В воровском жаргоне, возможно, и появилось слово блатной как синоним к слову кровный.

ПО БЛАТУ – ПО ЛИСТУ БУМАГИ

(1) Когда большевики экспроприировали имущество у буржуазии, то это законно награбленное добро они складировали в специальных хранилищах — спецхранах. Охранять спецхран и выдавать по предъявлению специального мандата  вещи назначался неподкупный человек, на такую должность чаше брали немцев из числа бывшей складской администрации. Немец, плохо говоривший по-русски, требовал от просителя бумагу с печатью. Так и говорил: "Blat, blat..." — и без этой "блат" ничего не выдавал! С тех пор так и повелось — чтоб что-то достать, нужно иметь блат.

(2) Языковеды утверждают, что выражение по блату (незаконным образом, как у блатных) вошло в разговорную речь из воровского жаргона в 30-е годы, замечая, что в словаре Даля его нет. У Даля его, действительно,  нет, но в разговорную речь оно вошло всё-таки РАНЬШЕ.  По блату – это благодаря выгодному знакомству, через нужных людей. А уже к концу ХIХ века слово перенял преступный мир

Русский блат возник во времена Петра I и происходит от голландского blat или немецкого Blatt (лист бумаги). В такой блат вносили имена бояр, откупившихся от обрезания длинных рукавов, ношения немецкой одежды, бритья бород, необходимости отдавать своих недорослей для обучения ремеслу за границей и т. д. Помещённых в сей блат именовали блатными, то есть избранными. 
.

Comment: Много  вроде  бы  интересных  версий  и  ни  одного  убедительного  варианта ( это  относится  ко  всем  ответам ).